# Convert and upload data from a form to a CSV file and allow file upload using php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to:

1. save the data entered in a form to a CSV file, which gets attached as a CSV file and sent via email and
2. allow users to upload their own file, which also gets sent via email

I've been able to generate the CSV file and save the data in it, and email the file uploaded in part 2,

However, I'm unable to send the CSV file created in part 2 as attachment.

I am using `PHPMailer`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my formprocess file.

```
<?PHP

*/
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    function Validate() { return false;}
    function GetError(){ return '';}
}

class FGContactForm
{
    var $receipients;
    var $errors;
    var $error_message;
    var $name;
    var $email;
    var $message;
    var $from_address;
    var $form_random_key;
    var $conditional_field;
    var $arr_conditional_receipients;
    var $fileupload_fields;
    var $captcha_handler;

    var $mailer;

    function FGContactForm()
    {
        $this->receipients = array();
        $this->errors = array();
        $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
        $this->conditional_field='';
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
        $this->fileupload_fields=array();

        $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    }

    function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
    {
        $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
        session_start();
    }

    function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
    {
        $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
    }

    function SetFromAddress($from)
    {
        $this->from_address = $from;
    }
    function SetFormRandomKey($key)
    {
        $this->form_random_key = $key;
    }
    function GetSpamTrapInputName()
    {
        return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
    }
    function SafeDisplay($value_name)
    {
        if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
        {
            return'';
        }
        return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
    }
    function GetFormIDInputName()
    {
        $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());

        $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
        return 'id'.$rand;
    }


    function GetFormIDInputValue()
    {
        return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
    }

    function SetConditionalField($field)
    {
        $this->conditional_field = $field;
    }
    function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
    {
        $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
    }

    function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
    {

        $this->fileupload_fields[] =
            array("name"=>$file_field_name,
            "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
            "maxsize"=>$max_size);
    }

    function ProcessForm()
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!$this->Validate())
        {
            $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
            return false;
        }
        $this->CollectData();

        $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

        return $ret;
    }

    function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

    function GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $this->error_message;
    }
    function GetSelfScript()
    {
        return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    function GetName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    function GetEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    function GetMessage()
    {
        return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    }

/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */


    function SendFormSubmission()
    {
        $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

        $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

        $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";

        $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

        $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

        $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

        $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

        $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
        $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
        $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

        $this->AttachFiles();

        if(!$this->mailer->Send())
        {
            $this->add_error("Failed sending email!");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function CollectConditionalReceipients()
    {
        if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
          !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
          !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
        {
            foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
            {
                if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
                !empty($rec))
                {
                    $this->AddRecipient($rec);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Internal variables, that you donot want to appear in the email
    Add those variables in this array.
    */
    function IsInternalVariable($varname)
    {
        $arr_interanl_vars = array('scaptcha',
                            'submitted',
                            $this->GetSpamTrapInputName(),
                            $this->GetFormIDInputName()
                            );
        if(in_array($varname,$arr_interanl_vars))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function FormSubmissionToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
            {
                $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
                $value = nl2br($value);
                $key = ucfirst($key);
                $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>$key :</div><div class='value'>$value </div>\n";
            }
        }
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upload_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upload_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }        

            $filename = basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>File upload '$field_name' :</div><div class='value'>$filename </div>\n";
        }
        return $ret_str;
    }

    function ExtraInfoToMail()
    {
        $ret_str='';

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP address of the submitter:</div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";

        return $ret_str;
    }

    function GetMailStyle()
    {
        $retstr = "\n<style>".
        "body,.label,.value { font-family:Arial,Verdana; } ".
        ".label {font-weight:bold; margin-top:5px; font-size:1em; color:#333;} ".
        ".value {margin-bottom:15px;font-size:0.8em;padding-left:5px;} ".
        "</style>\n";

        return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLHeaderPart()
    {
         $retstr = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">'."\n".
                   '<html><head><title></title>'.
                   '<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
         $retstr .= $this->GetMailStyle();
         $retstr .= '</head><body>';
         return $retstr;
    }
    function GetHTMLFooterPart()
    {
        $retstr ='</body></html>';
        return $retstr ;
    }
    function ComposeFormtoEmail()
    {
        $header = $this->GetHTMLHeaderPart();
        $formsubmission = $this->FormSubmissionToMail();
        $extra_info = $this->ExtraInfoToMail();
        $footer = $this->GetHTMLFooterPart();

        $message = $header."Submission from 'contact us' form:<p>$formsubmission</p><hr/>$extra_info".$footer;

        return $message;
    }

    function AttachFiles()
    {
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];
            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            $filename =basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

            $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES[$field_name]["tmp_name"],$filename);

        }
    }

    function GetFromAddress()
    {
        if(!empty($this->from_address))
        {
            return $this->from_address;
        }

        $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $from ="nobody@$host";
        return $from;
    }

    function Validate()
    {
        $ret = true;
        //security validations
        if(empty($_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()]) ||
          $_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()] != $this->GetFormIDInputValue() )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 1 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
        if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
        {
            //The proper error is not given intentionally
            $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //name validations
        if(empty($_POST['name']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide your name");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("Name is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //email validations
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide your email address");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(strlen($_POST['email'])>50)
        {
            $this->add_error("Email address is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }
        else
        if(!$this->validate_email($_POST['email']))
        {
            $this->add_error("Please provide a valid email address");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //message validaions
        if(strlen($_POST['message'])>2048)
        {
            $this->add_error("Message is too big!");
            $ret = false;
        }

        //captcha validaions
        if(isset($this->captcha_handler))
        {
            if(!$this->captcha_handler->Validate())
            {
                $this->add_error($this->captcha_handler->GetError());
                $ret = false;
            }
        }
        //file upload validations
        if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
        {
         if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
         {
            $ret = false;
         }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
    {
        $ret=true;
        $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
        $extn = $info['extension'];
        $extn = strtolower($extn);

        $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
        if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
        {
            $this->add_error("Valid file types are: $valid_filetypes");
            $ret=false;
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
    {
        $size_of_uploaded_file =
                $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
        {
            $this->add_error("The file is too big. File size should be less than $max_size KB");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
    {
        if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function ValidateFileUploads()
    {
        $ret=true;
        foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
        {
            $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

            $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];

            if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
            {
                $this->add_error("Error in file upload; Error code:".$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
             !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }

            if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
            $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
            {
                if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
                {
                    $ret=false;
                }
            }

        }
        return $ret;
    }

    function StripSlashes($str)
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    /*
    Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
    data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
    if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
    */
    function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    /*Collects clean data from the $_POST array and keeps in internal variables.*/
    function CollectData()
    {
        $this->name = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
        $this->email = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);

        /*newline is OK in the message.*/
        $this->message = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message']);
    }

    function add_error($error)
    {
        array_push($this->errors,$error);
    }
    function validate_email($email)
    {
        return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
    }

    function GetKey()
    {
        return $this->form_random_key.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

}

?>
```

and my form

```
<?PHP

require_once("./include/formprocess.php");
require_once("./include/captcha-creator.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$captcha = new FGCaptchaCreator('scaptcha');

$formproc->EnableCaptcha($captcha);

//1. Add your email address here.
//You can add more than one receipients.
$formproc->AddRecipient('email@site.com'); //<<---Put your email address here


//2. For better security. 
// and put it here
$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('XsHVufPpgD9Epwl');

$formproc->AddFileUploadField('photo','jpg,gif,png',2024);
$formproc->AddFileUploadField('resume','doc,docx,pdf,txt,xls,xlsx,csv',2024);

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))

// Save as CSV

   //The Attachment

            $cr = "\n";



            $data .= "Name" . ',' . "Email Address" .$cr;
            $data .= "$name" . ',' . "email" .$cr;

            $fp = fopen('data.csv','a');
            fwrite($fp,$data);
            fclose($fp);

            $attachments[] = Array(
               'data' => $data,
               'name' => 'data.csv',
               'type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
            );


            //Generate a boundary string

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";


            //Add the headers for a file attachment


            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                       "From: {$from}\n" .
                       "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";




            //Add a multipart boundary above the plain message


            $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $text . "\n\n";






        // END of CSV formatting


{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {


        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Contact us</title>
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="contact.css" />
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/fg_captcha_validator.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<fieldset >
<legend>Contact us</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='photo' >Your photo:</label><br/>
    <input type="file" name='photo' id='photo' /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_photo_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='photo' >Resume:</label><br/>
    <input type="file" name='resume' id='resume' /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_resume_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <div><img alt='Captcha image' src='show-captcha.php?rand=1' id='scaptcha_img' /></div>
    <label for='scaptcha' >Enter the code above here:</label>
    <input type='text' name='scaptcha' id='scaptcha' maxlength="10" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_scaptcha_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <div class='short_explanation'>Can't read the image?
    <a href='javascript: refresh_captcha_img();'>Click here to refresh</a>.</div>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->




</body>
</html>
```

How to attach and send the data.csv file that has been generated by the from?

Comment: Please elaborate on "but i unable to send the CSV file", what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have added my form and process scripts to the original comment. Hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: You still have not said what the problem is. Why does your form processor create unneeded mail headers? If you're going to set `AltBody`, you need to do that *after* calling `msgHTML()`.

Comment: Im unable to attach the csv file that is being created with the user inputs. Only the file that the user uploads gets emailed.